# keyboard does not showing with text fields in iPhone

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextfield

I have a view with 2 text fields for the user inputs.But when clicking on those text fields,keyboard is not showing.I have connected the delegate and implemented the following method.username and password are my text fields.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)txts{
  [username resignFirstResponder];
  [password resignFirstResponder];
  return YES; 
}
```

Comment: Did you make connection of the textfields with your variable names in XIB?

Comment: it works on simulator.the issue is when running on device

Comment: and also delegate the textfields to file's owner?

Comment: yes. those all i have done.When clicking on that text fields,a blinking cursor shows.But no keyboard

Comment: recently i have upgraded my Xcode version to Xcode 4.2 from Xcode 4.1.Will that affect my code?The code was first wrote in Xcode 4.1.At that time there was no issue about the key board.

Answer (score 0):

Are they over released? Are they nil? Try assigning them to the first responder.

```
 [textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

then implement `BOOL` method

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {

    return YES;

    }
```

Are you sure you have set the delegate?

```
 [textField setDelegate:self];
```

Did you connect them properly if you used them in XIB?

Comment: where do i give  [textField becomeFirstResponder];?In viewdidload?

Comment: no.it is not showing any errors or warnings.U have any idea about my problem?

Comment: i corrected it myself.sorry guys. the issue was in my "should autorotate" method